# Electric DC Motor

Tags: dc-motor

What happens if I made a DC motor with magnets that are stronger than they should be,will the motor require too much electricity, can this affect it's performance (rpm,torque,etc...)?

Comment: Most likely : more torque, less RPM, same efficiency. Assuming the rest of the magnetic circuit can carry the increased field strength. If it can't, you've just spent more money on magnets than you needed to.

Answer (score 1):

If the magnet was say twice as strong the motor would turn at half speed if the supply volts was kept the same and the load was light. So you would double the supply volts to keep the speed the same. For a given torque the current would halve.

On the face of it things appear to be the same, but this halving of current means that the copper losses in the windings are divided by four. Hence stronger magnets allow more efficient PM motors to be constructed. This is why you see larger PM machines than were around when I was a child.